# ¿Cómo divido una matriz cuadrada en N matrices cuadradas más pequeñas?

Tags: c, algoritmos, matrices

En concreto tengo que dividir una matriz cuadrada de 128*128 elementos en submatrices de 32x32 o de 64x64 elementos. ¿Podrían ayudarme a encontrar una solución general para este problema? Todo lo tengo que realizar utilizando arreglos bidimensionales en C.

El código que tengo hasta el momento es el siguiente; está pensado para ser escalable por lo que por el momento funciona sobre una matriz de 8x8. Sin embargo se queda en un bucle imprimiendo unos hasta que mato el proceso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){

int matriz[8][8]= {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
        { 9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16},
        {17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24},
        {25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32},
        {33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40},
        {41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48},
        {49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56},
        {57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64}
   
    };
int n=4;
int aux;
int largo=8;
int alto=8;
for(aux=0;aux<largo;aux++){
    if(aux=0){
        for(int i=0; i<((8/n)*2); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++)
                printf(" %d ", matriz[i][j]);
        printf("\n");}
    }
    else{
        if((aux+1)%4==0){    
        for(int i=aux; i<((8/n)*2); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<n; j++)
                printf(" %d ", matriz[i][j]);
        printf("\n");}
    }
    }
    
 }
}
```

Comment: Se me ocurre utilizar un bucle `for` que vaya incrementando una variable y que, mediante el operador `%` sepa en qué posición estás. Tanto para el eje X como el eje Y. De todos modos, sin pudieras postear el código que tienes hecho hasta la fecha podríamos proporcionarte una mayor ayuda.

Comment: Justo intenté eso y fallé, adjunto el código y su comportamiento

Comment: `if(aux=0){` Ahi estas asignado, no comparando. Y como estas asignado 0 la
condicion siempre sera falsa.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu objetivo es tomar una sub-sección de una matriz más grande, lo que debes hacer es trabajar con desplazamientos (*offsets*), te propongo lo siguiente:

```
void copia(int origen[][8], int tamanyo_origen, int destino[][3], int tamanyo_destino, int x, int y)
{
    int vertical = y;
    for (int fila = 0; fila != tamanyo_destino; ++fila)
    {
        int horizontal = x;
        for (int columna = 0; columna != tamanyo_destino; ++columna)
        {
            destino[fila][columna] = origen[vertical][horizontal++];
        }
        ++vertical;
    }
}
```

La función `copia` recibe una matriz cuadrada junto a una matriz cuadrada más pequeña, un tamaño y unas coordenadas, copiará los valores de las coordenadas en la matriz más pequeña, así `copia(matriz, 8, destino, 3, 1, 0);` copiará en `destino` una matriz de cuadrada de tamaño 3 empezando en las coordenadas `{1,0}`.

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xVLtipxAEPy98xSTDYEV64LzqbK3eREjQdS9G9jVw3MPzeGzb2Yc9eAI5GdgxLGrre6u6vLhqSzv96@mKS@3qqaPr31l2u/PPwh5a01Fy/bFFAfT9LTtzFPdZHmW5KAu0BfXohnbXx7wsap@7U3T2izxKWtBfHDwrzEg72Tnbm9115uyuNATHY9kd247Ohc9m0thY9HR376cPvMdaRg6KCA7SzVzPduGfrdNP7MNlu2Drmwvt2uzMK4ffyddUMs7E@/WyVyxPFvQ3DItuqwT5NlH/TDMXfnJPmG4JtjIRCZCXD/XwjSHTYRr0ds/rb72nKir@k4ZKAcVoBJUgWrQGDSZMIMpWATGwDiYAJNgCkx7kMVgCVgKHoEzcA4uwKUHuQLX4DF4Ap5CRBAMgntQCAgJoSA0RAyRQKSQkQclg@SQAlJCKkgNGUMuDckUKoJiUBxKQEkoBbU0pGKoBCqFjqAZNIcW0HKi05H4@VeJhdseF/TL52WxU4NuS2QFscpEgcva3B29r6NzVDgP3YLN7m0pg08ZtpTBGbx76Sx4Puy/VXS/VcnGPBvywDm44j@bfTD794/e3PmPvXV1f@saS0am@/0P)</kbd>.